# How to turn header on while querying CSV file using SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark SQL can query on CSV file directly. See the example below.

```
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM csv.`csv/file/path/in/hdfs`")
```

However, how can we let Spark that there's a header line in the CSV file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a view:

```
spark.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW df
             USING csv 
             OPTIONS (header "true", path "csv/file/path/in/hdfs")""")
spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM df""")
```